# Accessing feature service properties for pop ups in AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, arcade

Within an AGOL web map/app, is there a way to access feature service properties as a variable to show in the feature popup?

I would like to be able to show when the feature service was last updated in the popup on my web map/app. I have the edit date listed in the feature service description and can change it via the arcgis python api, and I can also see the last edit date in the feature service details and through the rest service. Is there any way of accessing any of these locations through Arcade to show them in the feature pop up? There is the obvious work around of including an "Updated Date" field for each row in the feature service and then calling that, but the service already exists and is updated through a separate workflow, so changing the schema now would break the existing structure.

Comment: here you are thinking of pulling info in your popups from the rest or the item details?

Comment: @YogeshChavan, yes. There are a handful of different "last update" parameters in the item details that I'm hoping to access the same way you'd access a field value when creating a pop up. For feature field values, Arcade uses the $feature.[field] syntax, but i'd like to access the feature service details.